# VBA - ws.ExportAsFixedFormat

Tags: excel, vba

I want to automatically export each sheet to a PDF in a specific folder and rename them with a date suffix.
However, I encounter an error (*run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument*) in the following line: `ws.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=pdfFileName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False`

Here is the full code:

```
    <Sub LoopSheetsSaveAsPDF()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim savePath As String
    Dim currentDate As String
    Dim pdfFileName As String

    savePath = ThisWorkbook.Path
    currentDate = Format(Date, "yymmdd")
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        pdfFileName = savePath & "\" & Replace(ws.Name, " ", "_") & "_" & currentDate & ".pdf"
        ws.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=pdfFileName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Thank You

I want to remove the error, so the code works

Comment: You get WHAT error?

Comment: run-time error '5':
Invalid procedure call or argument

Comment: Code as is works fine for me. using Excel 365. msgbox the filename, matbe an error there?

Comment: ur asking my excel file name? its "TES MAKRO". I dunno how to msgbox :D, new here

Comment: You can get `run-time error '5':` if the sheet is hidden. You can use a `If ws.Visible = True Then:  {print code} : End If` block to skip hidden sheets.

Comment: [VBA msbbox function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/msgbox-function)

Comment: Example `msgbox "Hello World " & pdfFileName`

Comment: Are you sure that there are no invalid characters in your file name?